# Is there a way to automate debugging on Visual Studio via scripting?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, automation

In my project i'm using Visual C++ and at some point I had a requirement to set a "data breakpoint" for each memory address in a function which takes that memory address as a parameter.

Is that possible to do somehow? via scripting etc?

Comment: I usually call DebugBreak() function in-case I want to deliberately break via code. Not sure if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, i didn't know DebugBreak function, but that does not solve my problem unfortunately. I need to set several  data breakpoints and want to atomize it.

Comment: while we are doing heavy debugging, we install debug points in various places. Just to preserve the trace path, we can store the debug points in a xml file (VS supports this). Next time we launch the app in debug mode it will reload all the break points (though xml file) and stops there. unfortunately, this is not through any source code.